# Azure ADF Lookup a distinct list for a following 'For each activity'

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a Lookup activity to get a list of values from a csv file. I want to want to loop through a distinct list of one of the columns (other columns are not identical.) I can build an array object with just the column I'm interested in but how can I make it a distinct list for a following loop?   [image: Duplicate country in list is not what I want]

Comment: Is the Lookup out to a database?  You could just do `SELECT DISTINCT` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [union()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#union) function to get the unique list from the array.

**Example:**

1. I have a list of array values in a variable.

[image]

2. Using **set variable** activity, get the **unique** list from the array.

`@union(variables('array_list'),variables('array_list'))`

[image]

3. Output of set variable activity.

[image]